# Themal Energy Harvester Trouble

Tags: peltier

[image: Peltier and breakout board]

So basically, I just recieved my LTC3108 breakout board and wanted to test it. The way it (supposedly) works is you solder two specific points on the board together to indicate a specific output voltage. You can see my two joints in the bottom right side of the board, which gives an output of 2.35v at Vout. If you look at my white led, it is set in Vout and my peltier is soldered into Vin. When holding down on the peltier, it doesn't light. The multimeter reads absolutely no voltage going into Vout. Does anything look wrong with my set up? Here is a link to where I bought it with info on its usage in the description.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/331654685113

Comment: What do you mean "hodling down" on TEC? How do you create temperature difference across TEC plates?

Comment: Also, are you sure that your LED's Vf is under 2.35V?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel if the multimeter read 0 voltage at Vout, then that would be why it's not lighting. Either way though, its a 1.8v LED.

Comment: @AliChen I use my hand's heat on one side and copper heatsink on the opposite.

Comment: Are PGD and/or VLDO from the LTC3108 coming up?

Comment: And what is on the opposite side, who is cooling it? I just tried my TEG, one side in contact with an ice pack, another with a hand. I got only about 400mV into 20k load (assumed DMM impedance). Not much to harvest from, no matter how sophisticated the circuit is. Did you try to remove the LED, and just measure if the circuit is harvesting anything at all?

Comment: @Ali Chen the LTC3108 is supposed to boost voltage from as low as 20mv to the specified voltage, in this case 2.35v. So with my aluminum heatsink and my hand's heat, it should be plenty.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel none of the outputs are reaching 2.35v. No where close, in fact all closer to 0.

Comment: @Deadfult -- try taking the LED off and seeing if it can get there open-circuit.  Also, what storage capacitors does the board have on it, and what voltage is VStore reaching (with the LED on and off in turn)?

Comment: @Deadfult, Plenty? Mine TEC makes 300mV over 10 Ohms maximum I can get between an arm and cold ice block. This is 1mW only. What does your TEC do?